# Fluctuations in electricity use while we are on vacation

Tags: electrical, heater

We went on vacation for two weeks recently and I noticed that our PG&E bill had some unusual behavior.

- Our overall bill wasn't that much lower than it was when we were home.
- Different days had very different amounts of energy use. One day (63 degrees average temperature) had 5 kWh of energy usage and a few days later (65 degrees average temperature) PG&E reported 15 kWh of energy usage.

What could cause such fluctuations in our electricity use? We closed the windows and blinds and unplugged most disposable electronics except the TV (which was turned off), refrigerator and a small Coway air purifier (left on by accident). The refrigerator was installed within the last five years.

A smart home app sends alerts any time the doors open or close, and it did not fire for the entire vacation, so there's no chance family members or kids were secretly home.

We have a gas heater, no A/C and the we set the thermostat to "eco mode" = 50 degrees = while we were gone.

**edit** Here's a photo from the low energy day, 5kWh of energy use:

[image: Hour by hour chart of low energy usage]

And high energy usage - note the different scale on left hand side.

[image: hour by hour chart of high usage]

No one was in the house on either of these days.

Comment: maybe somebody is pirating your power

Comment: Perhaps the fridge had to work harder on the warmer day? Is it a small unit or a barn sized one with cold water fountain, beer and slushies all built-in?

Comment: You have a smart meter, and the energy usage numbers aren't estimates, right? Also, since your heat is electric, there shouldn't be any correlation between the temperature and the power usage.

Comment: I have a meter provided by PG&E with a digital readout of the power consumption. I am basing the energy usage numbers based on a dashboard provided by opower.com (available through the PG&E dashboard) It's possible the numbers are estimates though I believe PG&E uses the same ones to compute the bill.

Not sure how you define "small unit", it's a side by side refrigerator + freezer that's pretty common in an American household.

It's possible someone is pirating my power but very unlikely based on the configuration of our house.

Comment: My fridge uses about 180kW/h per year and it is a standard fridge... Yours sounds a lot larger, so expect the use to go up by a factor of 5 or 10 at least...

Comment: Average temperature doesn't mean much. What were the highs and lows? Also, what appliances remained hooked up that could draw 400W or more?

Comment: Any sump pumps? Powered attic ventilation? Does the fridge catch sunlight that might warm it up and run more? I usually blame the cat if all else fails. And I wouldn't use avg temp as a gauge, avg of 130 and 0 is 65.

Comment: No sump pumps or attic, and we drew the blinds, so it shouldn't have been in direct sunlight. Temp fluctuation was from about 59 to 75, I believe.

Comment: It's an Ikea fridge. Per https://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/pdf/buying_guides_fy15/Appliances_bg.pdf it's supposed to use 517 kWh per year, so roughly 1.5 per day. It seems unlikely to cause a spike up to 15 kWh.

Comment: Well now, that's what you call "going above and beyond" on my temperature question.   We still need to know more about your loads, though; otherwise we'll be playing "20 questions" which we kind-of are right now.

Comment: Defrost cycle on the fridge? Runs a hefty heater for a while to melt ice off the coils, then the fridge has to run to cool back down. On the thievery angle, got any outside outlets? A dishonest person with an electric car and an extension cord who knew you were away could affect your use without opening a door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way anyone could have guessed this, but FYI, I discovered that our meter was reading the usage from our upstairs neighbors apartment, and their meter was reading the usage from our apartment.

The reason the energy usage was high was because we were being billed for the usage of our upstairs neighbors, who were still home and running the laundry and dishwasher while we were on vacation.

You can verify this (with PG&E at least) by comparing the meter number on your bill to the meter number that corresponds to your apartment. If they don't match, you may be being billed for someone else's usage.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any electrical convenience outlets on your house ? While your home's inside is secure, what about the outside ?

I would look into the possibility of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You say, “Energy Use”, but really it’s your electrical use you’re concerned about.

The item that uses the most energy in any home is the heating/cooling. However, you indicate that you have gas heat and no cooling. Therefore, that would not affect your electric bill whether you’re on vacation or not.

The second most energy user is usually the water heater...which is affected by laundry, bathing, dishes, etc. Not doing these activities could significantly reduce your electric bill.

Cooking is also something that uses a significant amount of electricity...oven, toaster, crockpot, etc. If you don’t use these a lot normally, then you would not see much change when on vacation.

Last is lights, chargers, etc. These use minor amounts of electricity, so no use when you’re on vacation would not reduce your total cost by much...

I would focus on checking the water heater. If it’s cycling on and off it could affect you electric bill the most.

It’s curios how the utility knows how much energy you used each day...did you get a printout of you daily use? Is this normal getting this from your utility?

I’d expect my electricity use to be fairly consistent day-to-day when no one is in the house for two weeks. (Do you suspect teenagers giving your security access code to friends and neighbors?) Is there anything on a timer, like pool heater, sauna, roomba, etc.

Comment: Edited the question to mention electricity specifically.

Comment: We have a digital meter and a dashboard through opower.com that reports the daily usage rounded to the nearest kWh. It's possible it's inaccurate.

Comment: No teenagers or family, at least, if anyone was in the house they did not go in through any of the doors, otherwise our contact sensors on the doors would have notified us that someone opened or closed them.

Comment: Could the water heater be involved at all in powering the operation of the fridge?

Comment: @KevinBurke Not at all.  The problem with this question is that **we have no idea what your appliances are**.  Therefore any possible answer is going to involve wild reaches of guesswork.  For instance my best guess is your dual-1080 gaming PC got hacked and was used to mine bitcoin, because that would explain 400W 24x7.   Because this is so unanswerable, I'm considering voting to close.

Comment: Hi, I listed the appliances I thought could be running - a fridge and a purifier, and a TV turned off that could have possibly been drawing power anyway. Everything else was turned off. I don't have a bitcoin gaming rig and if I did I would have unplugged it when I went on vacation.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that each day is separately accounted for during your vacation. Dashboards read smart meters once a day, usually around midnight and compare that reading to the day before to get the daily usage. If, for some reason, they don't read it on a particular day, which does happen due to computer problems, etc., the next day's reading will appear to be twice as much. Sometimes they will go back and correct it but not always.

Comment: I've worked directly with smart meters, created dashboards, etc. Typically a smart meter will produce a **lot** of data and have a decent memory (days or even weeks of 15-minute data), so a problem transmitting data will result in a delay in the dashboard, but *if designed properly* will not result in any gaps or double-ups. Of course, things are not always designed properly...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I guess if this were to happen I would expect a small day to be followed by a big day and I don't really see that in the data.